# Java dynamic proxy questions

Tags: java

1.Does dynamic proxy instance subclass the target class? 
The java doc says the proxy instance implements "a list of interfaces", says nothing about subclassing, but through debugging, I saw that the proxy instance did inherit the target class properites.What does the "a list of interfaces " mean? Can I exclude those interfaces implemented by target class ?

2.Can I invoke target class specific methods on a proxy instance?

3.
I think dynamic proxy is an interface methods invocation proxy but rather than a target class proxy, is that right (I am deeply infected by hibernate proxy object concept)?

Comment: Hibernate uses CGLIB to proxy classes, java.lang.reflect.Proxy can only proxy interfaces. And CGLIB creates a subclass to be able to proxy a class...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're talking about the `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` class: there's no such thing as a "target class" in general.

The proxy is [constructed](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance(java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class[],%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler)) by specifying a list of interfaces that the proxy object will implement, and an invocation handler whose [`invoke()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.reflect.Method,%20java.lang.Object[])) method all method calls on the proxy will be forwarded to. The invocation handler can do anything with them, including forwarding them to a "target class" instance it holds a reference to.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt:Thanks,Micheal.As you quoted, the "target class" is the class the Invocation handler holds reference to. Does the Invocation Handler has to hold this kind of reference? The method.invoke() inside the invoke method of InvocationHandler must receives a implementation of the proxy interfaces?

Comment: If we did not pass an implementation of proxy interfaces to method.invoke(), it's meanless to invoke a blank implementation on the proxy instance we created.If we pass this reference, why don't we call the instance method directly?

Comment: @Tony: no, this "target class" is an implementation detail, not a general concept. The invocation handler can do absolutely anything, much more than just forwarding calls. A typical example is a generic implementation of interfaces that consist only of matching getters and setters, which stores properties in a HashMap. Simply forwarding the calls and doing nothing else would indeed be pointless. But if you do something else on top of forwarding, it's a way to implement AOP.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you have misunderstood. Every `Class` object passed to [getProxyClass()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#getProxyClass) must be a class object for an interface, not a concrete class. So `String.class` would not be a valid argument but `List.class` would be. As it says "All of the Class objects in the interfaces array must represent interfaces, not classes or primitive types". As a result subclasses are irrelevant.
2. No (as classes are not relevant here, only interfaces). If you need to access them add an interface.
3. Correct.